# more than one select query in java - does not return any (from query2)

Tags: java

I have two methods in java to execute select query. and `function2` will execute when `query1` doesn't return any value. But my issue is with `query 2`, I am getting an empty result set. If I run the same query(`query 2`) in DB tool, I get some rows, but in the code, it returns null.

```
public class FetchData2 {

    private static Connection connection = null;


    public static Connection getConnection() {

        System.out.println("initial connection "+connection);   

        if (connection != null)
            return connection;
        else {
            // DB Connection
            try
            {   System.out.println("i am inside connection");             
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connection");
                System.out.println("Connection estabilished"+connection);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Connection error1: "+e);
            } 
            return connection;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Elements2> getAllElements2(String sino,String irepno) {     
        connection = FetchData2.getConnection();
        ArrayList<Elements2> itemListinsp = new ArrayList<Elements2>();     

        try {
            Statement statement1=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery("query1");


            while(rs.next()) {  
                Elements2 iteminsp=new Elements2(); 
                iteminsp.setParameters(rs.getString("parameters"));
                iteminsp.setSpecifications(rs.getString("specifications"));
                iteminsp.setActual1(rs.getString("actual1"));
                iteminsp.setActual2(rs.getString("actual2"));
                iteminsp.setActual3(rs.getString("actual3"));
                iteminsp.setActual4(rs.getString("actual4"));
                iteminsp.setActual5(rs.getString("actual5"));
                itemListinsp.add(iteminsp);
            } 

        con.close(); // added these lines
        rs.close();
        ps.close();           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection query exection error: "+e);
        }

        return itemListinsp;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Elements2> getcritElements2(String icode) {
        connection = FetchData2.getConnection();
        System.out.println("I AM IN SECOND FETCH");
        ArrayList<Elements2> listcrit = new ArrayList<Elements2>();

        System.out.println("incoming icode: "+icode);

        try {
            Statement statementinsp=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsinsp = statementinsp.executeQuery("query2");

            if (!rsinsp.next() ) {
                System.out.println("no data");
            } 

            while(rsinsp.next()) {  
                Elements2 inspcrit=new Elements2(); 
                inspcrit.setParameters(rsinsp.getString("parameters"));
                inspcrit.setSpecifications(rsinsp.getString("specifications"));
                listcrit.add(inspcrit);
            }            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection query exection error: "+e);
        }
         System.out.println(listcrit.size());
       System.out.println(listcrit.get(0).getParameters());
       System.out.println(listcrit.get(0).getSpecifications());
        return listcrit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close your `ResultSet` and your `Statement` and your `Connection` in that order!

*Addition:* (try-with-resources only work with Java at least version 1.7 and closes the Connection, ResultSet and the Statement for you in the correct order (even if an exception within the try-block occurs!))

```
public class FetchData2 {

   public static Connection getConnection() {

      System.out.println("initial connection "+connection); 

      // DB Connection
      Connection connection = null;
      try {
            System.out.println("i am inside connection");             
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connection");
            System.out.println("Connection estabilished"+connection);
      } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection error1: "+e);
      } 
      return connection;
   }
}

public static ArrayList<Elements2> getAllElements2 (String sino,String irepno) {        
    ArrayList<Elements2> itemListinsp = new ArrayList<Elements2>();     

    try (Connection connection = FetchData2.getConnection();
         Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery("query1")) {

        while(rs.next()) {  
            Elements2 iteminsp = new Elements2();   
            iteminsp.setParameters(rs.getString("parameters"));
            iteminsp.setSpecifications(rs.getString("specifications"));
            iteminsp.setActual1(rs.getString("actual1"));
            iteminsp.setActual2(rs.getString("actual2"));
            iteminsp.setActual3(rs.getString("actual3"));
            iteminsp.setActual4(rs.getString("actual4"));
            iteminsp.setActual5(rs.getString("actual5"));
            itemListinsp.add(iteminsp);
        }          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection query exection error: "+e);
    }
    return itemListinsp;
}

public static ArrayList<Elements2> getcritElements2(String icode) {
    System.out.println("I AM IN SECOND FETCH");
    ArrayList<Elements2> listcrit = new ArrayList<Elements2>();

    System.out.println("incoming icode: "+icode);

    try (Connection connection = FetchData2.getConnection();
         Statement statementinsp = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rsinsp = statementinsp.executeQuery("query2")) {

        if (!rsinsp.isBeforeFirst() ) {
            System.out.println("no data");
        } 

        while(rsinsp.next()) {  
            Elements2 inspcrit=new Elements2(); 
            inspcrit.setParameters(rsinsp.getString("parameters"));
            inspcrit.setSpecifications(rsinsp.getString("specifications"));
            listcrit.add(inspcrit);
        }            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection query exection error: "+e);
    }
    System.out.println(listcrit.size());
    System.out.println(listcrit.get(0).getParameters());
    System.out.println(listcrit.get(0).getSpecifications());
    return listcrit;
}
```

}

Comment: i have added a code to close all parameters. still i am getting null. please check my updated code and help me to find out

Comment: What is `ps.close`? You have to close the 3 things in the correct order - 1st the ResultSet, then the Statement and in the end the Connection. But in FetchData2 you return the old, closed Connection - that doesn't work if you've closed the Connection. So you always have to return a new Connection!